# Про оповещений при поступления сообщений.

Tags: php

Есть таблица messages, где хранятся сообщения, автор и получатель. И на странице пользователя есть раздел "Мои сообщения", вот как сделать когда при поступлении нового сообщения в ccылку "Мои сообщения" добавилось +1, или просевчивалось, что угодно главное чтобы было оповещение. Пожалуйста объясните и напишите мне, но не пишите словарный код, а реальный. Про обнуления active или равно 1 - я это незнаю, но если вы объясните - то узнаю.

Comment: наймите кодера

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as a messages WHERE view = 0");
echo $a[0];
```

А если хотите, чтобы появилась окошко или звук без обновление - вам PHP не сможет помочь)

Comment: mysql_query - у вас очепятка :) и к тому же echo $a[0] ничего нужного не даст...

Comment: @Node_pro, а зафетчить? :)

Comment: то, что нужно..

Answer (score 0):

Ну php все равно придется использовать, просто нужен еще функционал на клиенте. Делайте периодически запрос на сервер с помощью ajax, лучше использовать jquery

Comment: > лучше использовать jquery

зачем?